# [jquery]How do I add file uploads dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I want to upload multiple files, so I want to add upload fields dynamically through jquery. Now I can do it if I have a button like "add another field", and append the new upload to the form, but I want to do it a bit differently.

Initially the form should have one input field, after the user selects a file to upload I want to immediately add another upload field. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `input` element has a `change` event that gets fired when the form field changes. So you can use the [event-delegating form of `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler):

```
$('selector_for_your_form').on('change', 'input[type=file]', function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    form.append(/* ... markup for the new field ... */);
});
```

The `change` event is actually hooked up to the form, but only fires the handler if the event passed through an element matching the selector `input[type=file]`. (jQuery ensures that the `change` event propagates, even in environments where it doesn't by default.)

Live example: *(I assume your markup would be a bit more interesting — and certainly better-looking — than shown there)*

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('form').on('change', 'input[type=file]', function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    form.append('<input type="file">');
  });
});
```

```css
  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
  p {
    margin: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='file'>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Notes:

- If you need to support obsolete versions of jQuery without `on`, you can use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) which is like the delegating form of `on` but with the arguments in a different order.
- If you need to support obsolete browsers *and* obsolete versions of jQuery, the `change` event may not bubble and older jQuery didn't make it bubble for `delegate` (even though it did when hooked directly).

In either case, see the [2011 version of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4578622/3) *(with a minor change to the JSBin links)* for examples, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
<input type="file" name="file" onChange="if ($(this).val() != '' {addNewfileInput();}">
```