# How to add a drop-down element dynamically when a radio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, ajax, drop-down-menu, radio-button

When I click the radio button, I want to display a drop-down list element dynamically in the same form. There is no button, only a radio button. I am looking for a solution using JavaScript and Ajax.

Comment: Show us what you tried!

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? Might be easier to give advice that way.

Comment: if you have test-server, please give also the link so that we can see it..

Comment: There is an event when the radion button is (un)checked...

Comment: Look into jQuery, you'll grow to like javascript again :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is similiar problem, you just have to adjust that instead of input with your select control, and put your data for select into Javascript array then just add it .
[Adding file inputs dynamicly with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843150/adding-file-inputs-dynamicly-with-jquery)

Comment: do not bother that there are file inputs* just adjust that to add your dropdown list instead of inputs. Hope it helps.